# Short circuited

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit

Hi was getting ready to hang a light when removing wires outta the box the touched and kicked off the breaker, once I turned breaker back on light and a few other lights and plugs don’t work now I have removed all the outlets and light switches to check connection but I have no luck what should I do now as a small portion of my home is powerless

Comment: Call an electrician. If you didn't know enough to shut off the breaker before starting to work, you should have called an electrician from the beginning for your own safety.

Answer (score 2):

Since this started after a high current event and you reset the breaker the problem is usually a weak connection.

Backstabs are the most common source of this problem.
If you don’t have a meter or a receptacle tester you can troubleshoot by using a plug in lamp and working to the service panel.

Most homes are wired from the panel in a chain so I try to figure out what is not working on that circuit looking for the first working receptacle or switch.

This is where you find the problem the last working device or first non working device, most commonly a back stab or push in wire connector.

If you find the device turn the breaker off and pull it out and don’t see anything wrong and put it back in . then turn the power back on, if things start working that device will fail again and should be replaced or at a minimum wires moved to screw terminals.

If everything is still dead the problem also can be at a wire nut or a broken wire and the least common place is in the panel.

So you are looking for a loose or broken wire at a backstab /wirenut or screw. It is normally white or black.

Please turn off circuit breakers prior to working on circuits. There are non contact voltage testers that can alert you if there is power there test before touching! some for 5$, professional models usually run 15-20$ , add a receptacle / GFCI tester that can be purchased for 10$ or less should be tools every homeowner has to help them do basic electrical work safely and correctly.